# Why click function is not working on page, but it works on console?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract LinkedIn reactions of one of my connection's post. I want to click on an element using Selenium & python. On console it works, it said that the element is clickable but on the page it triggers nothing.

```
post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='occludable-update ember-view']")
like = (post.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count']"))

print(like)
try:
    like.click()
    print('Element is clickable')
except WebDriverException:
    print('Element is not clickable')

--------
Output:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f08fca13c4b757b1e07f510ac3e87d5b", element="daf1ed78-87f1-4742-ab6b-155bc3bbec2f")>
Element is clickable
```

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: Just go to someone profile -> activity -> posts or ```https://www.linkedin.com/in/```linkedinName```/detail/recent-activity/shares/```

Comment: Ahh do you want to click on reaction link ? on all the post or just the first one ?

Comment: @PaulViorel - It triggers nothing means - are you not able to see the pop-up showing the names? Does the browser window close instantly? When I tried your code, with `time.sleep(5)` after `like.click()` , was able to see the pop-up.

Comment: I want to collect all the reactions from all posts. But for the beginning I wanted to collect from the first 10.

Comment: @pmadhu let me try with time.sleep, I will give it a try in 5 min.

Comment: @pmadhu yeaa.. thanks.. it works with ```time.sleep(5)```...

Answer (score 0):

If it's the reaction button you wanna click, then I would suggest to have :

1. Reliable locators.
2. Explicit waits.

**Code : -**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='occludable-update ember-view']")))
like = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count']/..")

try:
    time.sleep(2)
    like.click()
    print('Element is clicked')
except:
    print('Element was not clicked')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It works with ```time.sleep(5)``` before clicking code line. I will give it a try using your method because it looks better.

Comment: yeah mostly it would work, cause `WebDriverWait` is basically an explicit waits so is 1time.sleep(5)`, but time.sleep is worst of it's kind since it set a thread freeze for defined amount of time.

Comment: Still not work when it finds more posts with reactions.. Maybe should I increase the second argument of WebDriverWait to 50 or more?

Comment: No, 20 should be sufficient. Are you looking for more than 1 element ?

Comment: Yep. For now I am looking for the first 10 post. But my goal is to get over 100+ posts reactions.

Answer (score 0):

Put Explicit wait until the pop-up is visible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='occludable-update ember-view']")
like = (post.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count']"))


print(like)
try:
    like.click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='social-details-reactors-tab__icon-container']")))
    print('Element is clickable')
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='social-details-reactors-tab__icon-container']//span[2]").text) # Prints the respective count of reactions.
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Element is not clickable')
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b2a5f095db328a8252be0e95f980f89f", element="28668dd1-22c5-423a-b17e-273ea29f3f86")>
Element is clickable
2
```